# How Schlieren Photography can be done using mobile camera?

Tags: camera-settings, cameraphones, physics, science, trick-photography

Can we do *Schlieren Photography* using good mobile phone camera (13-20 MP)? If yes how or can we do this photography only using professional digital camera? 
[Schlieren Photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieren_photography)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, and you can even do schlieren photography using old and poor mobile phone camera.**

It's not rocket science, yet it requires some equipment not normally found in a typical houshold (or even professional photographic studio), unless you are the amateur astronomer. The key ingredient is spherical mirror, which can be obtained from a cheap [newtonian telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_telescope) (higher class amateur newtonians have parabolic mirrors, which is also acceptable). Then it is just the matter of arranging the mirror, camera, and a light source in a configuration similar to this:

*(substitute the eye with a camera, and the light source can be used directly, no need for the second diagonal mirror - I'm just pasting the existing Wikipedia illustration on the [Focault knife-edge test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_knife-edge_test) to avoid licensing issues, feel free to replace it with a better picture)*

[image: Focault knife-edge test from Wikipedia]